Exponential Moment of Uniform Random Vector
Let $Z = (z_1,\dots, z_d)$ with $z_i$ i.i.d. uniform random variables on the interval $[a,b]$. I am interested in computing
$$
\mathbb{E} [\exp (\|Z\|^2)] = \mathbb{E} [\exp (z_1^2 + \dots z_d^2)].
$$
My attempt: we have the trivial upper bound $z_i \le b$ and so
$$
\mathbb{E} [\exp(\|Z\|^2)] \le e^{db^2}.
$$
For the lower bound, by Jensen's inequality
$$
\mathbb{E} [\exp{\|Z\|^2}] \ge \exp( \mathbb{E} |Z|^2) 
= \exp(d \mathbb{E} |z_1|^2)=\exp(d \frac{b^3 - a^3}{3 (b-a)}).
$$
Is there a better approach to get the exact expression, or perhaps tighter bounds?

Since each $z_i$ are iid random variables,
$$
    \mathbb{E}(\exp(\lVert Z \rVert^2)) = \mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left(\sum_{k = 1}^d z_k^2\right)\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(\prod_{k = 1}^d e^{z_k^2}\right) \stackrel{\text{independent}}{=} \prod_{k = 1}^d \mathbb{E}(\exp(z_k^2))
$$
Since $z_k \sim \mathcal{U}[a, b]$, we have
$$
    \mathbb{E}(\exp(z_k^2)) = \dfrac{1}{b - a}\int_a^b \exp(t^2)dt = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2(b - a)}[\text{erfi}(b) - \text{erfi}(a)]
$$
where $\text{erfi}$ is the imaginary error function:
$$
    \text{erfi}(z) = -i \cdot \text{erf}(iz)
$$
So the exact expression is,
$$
    \mathbb{E}(\exp\lVert Z \rVert^2) = \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2(b - a)}\right)^d [\text{erfi}(b) - \text{erfi}(a)]^d
$$
